# How to remove extra white spaces above the header and below footer in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, header, footer

I've developed a header and a footer in bootstrap and styled them in CSS. But there's a white space above the header and also below the footer. I'm not sure what is causing the white space to appear there.

Here's the code:

```
header.php

<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>

<title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all">

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
</head>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-static-top" id="topNav">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">

</nav>

footer.php

<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <p class="m-20 text-center text-white"><br></p>
</div>

</footer>

main.css

body {
margin-top: 60px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.footer {
position: sticky;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px; 
background-color: #CC0033;
}

#topNav {
position: sticky;
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 60px; 
background-color: #CC0033;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please try and reproduce the problem while inserting all relevant code by editing your question and clicking on Ctrl+M to insert the code.

Comment: Have you inspected element in browser tools and looked at the Layout and Rules (firefox) or Styles and Computed (chrome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're exactly trying to do but here's what I got,
the problem was with the CSS, but check what the classes in the nav are doing

```css
html,body {
height:100%;
}
body{
position:relative
}

.footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px; 
background-color: #CC0033;
  left:0;
}

#topNav {
position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 60px; 
background-color: #CC0033;
}
```

```html
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>

<title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all">

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
</head>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-static-top" id="topNav">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">

</nav>


<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <p class="m-20 text-center text-white"><br></p>
</div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Hey! This does remove the extra white spaces but, the body is overlapping the header in this case. How do I separate the body from the header?

Comment: do you mean that the header is now hidden under the body?? if this is the case then maybe adding a z-index on the header will do: #topNav{position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
line-height: 60px; 
background-color: #CC0033;z-index:2;}